# Set random backgroundColor from array

Tags: react-native

I spent around 2 hours on that and I really need help. I want to get random color from my array and then set backgroundColor of  to that one color. I copied my code there. https://jsfiddle.net/1x0k2ot4/

Thank you for every advice.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
        inputValue: '',
        backgroundColor: '',
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
    };
    this._handleTextChange = this._handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this._handleDeleteButtonPress = this._handleDeleteButtonPress.bind(this);
    this._setColor = this._setColor.bind(this);
}

_setColor() {
    const backgroundColor = backgroundcolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundcolors.length)];
    this.setState({
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor
    })
}<View style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, alignItems: 'center', height: 80, padding: 8, borderWidth: 1.5, borderColor: '#e0e0e0', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5,}}>
                                <Text style={styles.todoText}>{rowData}</Text>
                                <View>
                                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={handleDelete} style={styles.crossCloseButton}>
                                        <View>
                                            <Image style={styles.imgClose} source={{uri: 'http://playground.davidfutera.cz/close.png'}}/>
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                </View>
                            </View>
```

Comment: Include the behavior you are seeing now, the expected behavior (random color when? on load? etc?), and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, your post was a bit messy but I think this will help you out, if something gets an error tell me, it should work

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
  this.state = {
    bgColor: [
      'red',
      'blue',
      'yellow',
    ],
    selectedColor: '',
  };
}


componentDidMount() {
  this._getRandomColor()
}

_getRandomColor(){
  var item = this.state.bgColor[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.bgColor.length)];
  this.setState({
    selectedColor: item,
  })
}

<View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.selectedColor}}>
  <Text>Test</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: helpfull.. if you want use in render item guys only copy that  **this.state.bgColor[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.bgColor.length)]** and paste  style background color..

Answer (score 2):

It might be a lot easier and neater if you used a 6-digit hex code generator as provided by: https://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/. That way it is much more random and the code although a little more cryptic is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
**try this** 

const generateColor = () => {
        const CHHAPOLA = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)
          .toString(16)
          .padStart(6, '0');
        return `#${CHHAPOLA}`;
      };
    
    <View style={{backgroundcolor:generateColor()}}>
    </View>
```